# Вывод на печать введеных пользователем данных Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Привет. Использую на сайте форму Contact Form 7 для записи пациента на прием к врачу. Возникла необходимость, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку записаться, перед отправкой на эл.почту распечатался некое подобие талона с введенными пользователем данными в заранее подготовленном шаблоне.

Как это реализовать? Помогите пожалуйста.

Нашел как выполнить какое - то действие после успешной отправки:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
if(event.detail.contactFormId=="32"){ // 32 это id формы для отслеживания
alert("У формы №32 была нажата кнопка отправить");
}
}, false );
```

Открыть файл темы functions.php и в самое начало добавить код подключения этого файла:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts_1');
function add_scripts_1(){
wp_enqueue_script("cf7_list_function", get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/myscript.js',array('jquery'),"0.1",true);
}
```

вот сайт нашел, который демонстрирует функционал, о котором я писал выше, но к сожалению он не на вордпрессе сделан. [Центромед - онлайн запись](http://reg2.centromed.su/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не просьба помочь, это предложение сделать чужую работу. Вы бы глянули на в инструкцию, как задавать вопросы.

Comment: Формируете "страницу" для печати, через js отправляете на печать, в чем сложность то?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, нет, это не сделать работу, а подсказать решение как или с пом чего это реализовать.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "распечаталось"? Где, у кого? Что за "шаблон"?

Comment: @SeVlad, возможно, что меня достали бездельники, не знающие зачем нужно учиться в институте, и я не распознал, что за вопросом стоит реальная проблема, однако вопрос сформулирован плохо -  в нем нет информации, достаточной для содержательного ответа. Поэтому, ИМХО, автора вопроса есть смысл заглянуть в справку о том, как нужно формулировать вопросы на форуме. Вряд ли в той форме, как он поставлен, можно дать более точный ответ чем "...Формируете "страницу" для печати, через js отправляете на печать..."

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов а как меня достали отвечатели (а то и приниматели решений) которые ни в зуб ногой в предмете (ВП в данном случае), но лезут со своими советами и рекомендациями.

Comment: @SeVlad, дабы не плодить флуд, если автор скорректирует свой вопрос - я буду первый, кто поставит ему "+". Пока я плохо представляю, кто может здесь помочь с ответом - корректная постановка задачи отсутствует, и формулирование задачи, эта работа, которую автор перекладывает на других. В другую сторону, что такое ВП (это может быть визуальное программирование, вероятностный подход, ворлдпресс и еще куча интерпретаций) ?

Comment: Шохрух Султанов, чтобы Ваш комментарий дошел до нужного человека, начинаться он должен с символа собаки @ за которой следует имя. В Вашем случае это @SeVlad. Меняю минус на плюс, но над вопросом еще нужно поработать.

Comment: @Александр Муксимов, Спасибо

Comment: Между собакой и именем не должно быть пробела. Я увидел Ваш комментарий только потому, что не ушел с этой страницы форума

Comment: @SeVlad, Добавил скрин, ну в общем там герб центра еще будет, а остальное(фио, дата рождения, время заполнения, к какому врачу и т.д.)будет браться из формы

Comment: @ШохрухСултанов захламил вопрос не нужной инфой, на вопросы не ответил.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
вызов функции onclick="PrintDoc()"
<script>
function PrintDoc() {
var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1024,height=768,location=no,top=50px,left=50px');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/print.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">');

тут верстка талона

popupWin.document.write('</body></html>');
popupWin.document.close();

};
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как вот эти данные отправленные пользователем получить?

Comment: тут на примере записывают в переменную http://vincoding.com/passing-contact-form-7-data-thank-page/

Comment: @ШохрухСултанов, если ответ Вас устроил, не забудьте его принять (поставить зеленую галочку)

Comment: @Павел, Большое Вам спасибо.